# How do I change the default "File Name" value in SQL Server's Generate Scripts wizard?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm on SQL Server 2012.

The "Generate and Publish Scripts" wizard seems to remember the first path I gave it in the `Set Scripting Options → Save to File → File Name` box, but will under no circumstance remember any subsequent path I give it.  Where the hey is it storing this thing, anyway?

Things I have tried:

- Completing the wizard with a different value
- Searching the entire registry for the path the wizard likes
- Searching the entire filesystem for it
- Capturing all events in SysInternals' ProcMon and `Ctrl+F` for it

Nothing turns up in any case.  (It's using magic-storage space!)

Comment: It's probably encoded somewhere inside SQLStudio.bin.